# Background-image doesn't repeat-x Chrome on Android

Tags: css

I have a panorama image and repeating it endlessly. It's working on ***pc*** and ***ios device*** without a problem but not on ***Android Chrome***. When the image came to an end. it's going black. There is no problem on ***IOS Chrome***, so can't figure it out what is causing the problem.

Image div has these css:

```
#app .panorama {
  height: 400px !important;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-image: url(../images/app/vistas/noon/noon-20-f.jpg);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Then dynamically changing the position.

```
<div class="panorama" :style="{backgroundPosition:+count+'px center'}"></div>
```

There is no problem on ***pc*** or ***IOS Chrome***. So any idea what causing this problem?

Comment: What is your `viewport` meta?

Comment: I have this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">` @Dai